# Force close popup and re-open it Chrome Extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to force close an chrome extension and after closing it have it automatically re-open it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to close the popup window of your extension, the JavaScript code can close the popup window by itself forcibly.

```
window.close();
```

Unfortunately, we don't have any ways to open the popup window of BrowserAction/PageAction. Instead, you can change the tooltip text, the badge text and the background color with chrome.browserAction/chrome.pageAction APIs.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction